# IIS+PHP random Error 500.19

Tags: php, iis, iis-8.5

I'm running a WIMP stack on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, and I have a strange issue with IIS: After working for a random period of time (usually from several hours to days), most requests start to give the following error page:

[image: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error]

What is weird is that it works for a period of time. Changing the user access settings of web.config or restarting the website both work to resolve the issue temporarily, however it's a recurring problem.

I do realise that WIMP is not the most desirable stack (normally I'd opt for LNMP myself), however our website will be migrated to an ASP.NET app soon, and since we had to do a server upgrade beforehand, we opted into installing Windows on it to make the transition faster.

**EDIT:** After some testing, changing the NTFS permissions result in getting the same error until the website is restarted. Might have to do something with the issue?

Also, I'm running the website with a pre-selected user rather than pass-through, if that helps.

Comment: Same problem here. Either pre-selected user or pass-through gives the error. Have you sorted it out yet?

Comment: @LionetChen I believe I've fixed it somehow, but sadly I can't remember anymore how :( And we've moved to Azure since

Comment: Oh azure is a luxury I can't yet afford. And I'm not sure if Azure could avoid this problem. I installed a hotfix from [https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3007507/-http-error-500.19-error-when-you-browse-an-iis-8.5-website-in-windows] and I am observing now. Don't know if it fixes the problem.